# SQL insert with one row duplicate rows

Tags: sql, duplicates

From this table:

`DECLARE @tmp TABLE (id int, ahccs int, info varchar(25), endDate date)`

```
5   123 et  2012-09-15
2   321 et  2012-04-27
2   321 et  2012-04-27
2   321 et  2012-04-27
3   134 et  2012-04-27
```

How could I insert only these values to another table

```
5   123 et  2012-09-15
2   321 et  2012-04-27
3   134 et  2012-04-27
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the **Distinct** Keyword:

```
Create table TableName AS (Select Distinct [id] as id, [ahccs] as ahccs, [info] as info, [endDate] as endDate From Table_Name)
```

Comment: Edited so it's exactly the right syntax, you need to replace 'TableName' with the name of the table that you are pulling from and the name of the table to be created